# iOS App - Universal or separate targets?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud, ios-universal-app, universal-binary

I am trying to decide on whether or not an app should be Universal. Here are my requirements and questions related to each:

- In-app purchases. If you download the app on the iPhone and make a purchase, it should reflect that in the iPad version. Obviously you shouldn't have to buy it twice. Is this a dealbreaker? Is there some way to tie in-app purchases together in separate binaries?
- iCloud sync would be nice. The user creates content in the app and it would be great if the content created on the iPhone showed up in the iPad app. Again, does this mean it has to be universal?
- The app is large and contains a lot of images. The main drawback of a universal app is that I'm capped at 50MB over-air download, and that the single binary means iPhones get all the iPad images and vice versa.
- if I did make them two separate apps, do I separate everything in my Xcode project into two different targets and build that way?

Any answers to these questions or other things I should consider would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think,better option is  **Universal App**.

> The app is large and contains a lot of images. The main drawback of a
>   universal app is that I'm capped at 50MB over-air download, and that
>   the single binary means iPhones get all the iPad images and vice
>   versa.

Yes. This is the only difficulty that I measured. However you can clearly specify which images should be load in iPad and which should only load in iPhone by naming it separately.

If Im correct , you can use some thing like `myImage~iPhone.png or myImage~iPad.png`

Comment: True, but iPhone users still have to download 30MB+ worth of iPad images that they will never use.

Comment: "I'm capped at 50MB over-air download". is it possible check the device type and air only the files they need ?

Comment: No, because they are all included in the app binary file.